# Is it possible to whitelist-limit programs from accessing audio input?

Tags: audio, access-control

I guess I'm paranoid enough that I will install something bad, but not paranoid enough to think that I'll give that bad program privileges...

I want to allow microphone access only to the programs *I know* I allowed (and preferably in a way such that I can read the list later). Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent specific programs from accessing a specific device or service *directly*. (For example Ubuntu [does this with snaps](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityPermissions#Snap_interfaces).) However, Unix is designed around cooperating applications, so in practice it's very difficult to prevent a program from accessing a service indirectly, via another program that's allowed to access the service. For example, a program that can't access the microphone can probably still create a scheduled job (cron job) that does, or write instructions to do so in a session startup file, etc.

To isolate less-trusted programs, run them as a separate user. This will prevent the program from accessing any of your files unless you share them explicitly. Such a whitelist approach is necessary for security.

To prevent a user `sus` from accessing sound, block access to the old-style audio devices `/dev/dsp` and `/dev/adsp` (which I think are not used by any common application nowadays) and to the capture (`*c`) devices<sup>[1](https://programmer.group/alsa-architecture-sound-card-device-information.html)</sup> in `/dev/snd/`. From a startup file such as `/etc/rc.local`, run

```
setfacl -m u:sus:- /dev/adsp /dev/dsp /dev/snd/pcm*c
```

Note that this command must run on every boot, after `/dev` is mounted.

Make sure you aren't running a system-wide audio daemon such as pulseaudio that allows all users logged in on the console to access the microphone through it. (I don't think this is a default configuration in current distributions).

It's possible that some display managers will automatically grant a user access to the audio subsystem upon login. (I'm not very knowledgeable about display manager behavior.) Logging in in text mode and running `startx` will bypass this.